# Getting 000210 Error trying to wirte output to in_memory workspace in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, in-memory, error-000210

My model gives this error message when it tries to do the Clip function

[image: Error Message]

Here is the first half of the model showing the parameters used in the clip function

[image: Model]

I have successfully run this model when the clip function output was writing to disk but when I changed it to in_memory it stopped working. Any suggestions? I really don't want to write all 3000 files to my hard drive.

Comment: did you try removing the ".shp" from the Output Feature Class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in_memory workspace is styled as a gdb so it should work if you delete the ".shp"

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w0000005s000000

> "A table, feature class, or a raster written to the in-memory workspace
>   will have the source location of GPInMemoryWorkspace, as illustrated
>   below."

Comment: @see24, since mwil successfully answered your question, please mark his answer as "accepted" (checkbox next to the up/down arrows) to close this thread.  thanks!

Comment: +1 although my understanding is that while you can think of an in_memory workspace as being more like a file geodatabase it is not one