# Why does arcpy's Alter Field return "The tool is not licensed"?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, error-000824

According to the [help file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000198000000), the ALTER FIELD command is available at any license level.

> ```
> ArcGIS for Desktop Basic: Yes
> ```

Why am I getting a license error when trying to rename a field alias on a sample file geodatabase featureclass?

```
> arcpy.Describe(u"e:/test.gdb/testFC").fields[2].name
> u'oldfieldname'

> arcpy.AlterField_management(u"e:/test.gdb/testFC", "oldfieldname", "newfieldname"  ,"newaliasname")

> ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
> ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed.
```

This is a brand new, standard, empty featureclass which I just created for the purposes of this test.

Comment: 'TEXT' is not a valid field name? What is your feature class type? Perhaps you'll have better results not using a SQL reserved keyword like "TEXT_Val" see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123736/what-causes-error-000210-cannot-create-output-in-memory-and-from-arcpy/123747#123747. According to http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000198000000 the parameters go feature class, existing field, new name, new alias.. there's nothing there about the type.

Comment: Michael is right. Simply change "TEXT" to "newfieldname".

Comment: You referred to the **Add** FieldManagement doc

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I removed that to avoid confusion - it still fails with the same error message if I give a new field name. In fact I only want to change the alias but that's a separate question....

Comment: @StephenLead Alter fields is relatively new (10.2.2 I think) - what version are you using?  Whichever it is would not explain the error message but might help shine some light.

Comment: What about arcpy.AlterField_management(u"e:/test.gdb/testFC", "oldfieldname", new_field_alias="newaliasname")... I suspect though that it will have the same problem. Does the feature class support changing fields? I'm fairly sure you can't change a field in a shapefile but you can in pGDB (using Access) provided it's not indexed or 'special', I'm not sure about file geodatabase.. though field alias should be read/write. There's a related post http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255/how-to-change-feature-class-and-field-aliases-in-bulk in arcobjects for changing alias.

Comment: Will it work from the script, not Python window?

Comment: The field is not a string, drop the quotes around the old field name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why you would receive that error but to move forward I would try running the test code below (with values from your own feature class) from IDLE (or your own IDE).

It worked for me using ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop.

```
import arcpy

oldFieldName = arcpy.Describe("C:/temp/test.gdb/testFC").fields[4].name
oldFieldAlias = arcpy.Describe("C:/temp/test.gdb/testFC").fields[4].aliasName

print oldFieldName
print oldFieldAlias

arcpy.AlterField_management("C:/temp/test.gdb/testFC", oldFieldName, "NewField"  ,"NewAlias")

newFieldName = arcpy.Describe("C:/temp/test.gdb/testFC").fields[4].name
newFieldAlias = arcpy.Describe("C:/temp/test.gdb/testFC").fields[4].aliasName

print newFieldName
print newFieldAlias
```

Output was:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
OldField
OldAlias
NewField
NewAlias
```

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much was I was doing (unsuccessfully) in the original test. Looks like it's a problem with my installation, and/or a bug at 10.2. Thanks for verifying.