# Error 999999 exporting table view?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, table, error-999999

ArcGIS 10.1. When I try to export a table view with `CopyRows_management`, I get an invalid sql error. However, the sql statement by all accounts work fine. When I perform a `GetCount_management`, the results are correct. Is this a bug?

Code and error:

```
>>> sql = """"PARCEL_ID" IS NULL"""
>>> outTab = r"C:\Users\e1b8\Desktop\E1B8\Snapping\workspace\workspace.gdb\table"
>>> tab = r"C:\Users\e1b8\Desktop\E1B8\Snapping\Address_Tables_duplicate_addresses.gdb\_Geocode_Failures"
>>> arcpy.MakeTableView_management (tab, "tabView", sql)
<Result 'tabView'>
>>> arcpy.GetCount_management (tab).getOutput (0)
u'163083'
>>> arcpy.GetCount_management ("tabView").getOutput (0)
u'13688'
>>> arcpy.CopyRows_management ("tabView", outTab)
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>   
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 13547, in CopyRows
raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. 
An invalid SQL statement was used. 
An invalid SQL statement was used. 
[table] An invalid SQL statement was used. 
[SELECT * FROM table] The table was not found. [table] Failed to execute (CopyRows).  
>>>
```

Comment: I'm suspicious of a table name that starts with an underscore - if you drop that does it start working as expected?

Comment: Same result I'm afraid, with a table starting with a letter.

Comment: @PolyGeo is right.  The problem isn't the view, it's the output target.  FGDB tables must conform to SQL naming rules -- initial-alpha extra alphanumeric-or-underscore

Comment: "table" is probably a reserved word, as well.

Comment: Ah-ha. It was calling the table "table". Thanks.

Comment: As an FYI, starting the table name with an underscore didn't cause any issue with exporting once a legal output name was used.

Comment: I think a self-answer on this will be worthwhile - any causes of 999999 errors that have been tracked to resolution are worth documenting for future searches.

Comment: For some unknown reason, file geodatabases do *not* require standard SQL names (instead of first-alpha, it permits first-alpha-or-underscore).  I would strongly urge you, however, to ignore this fact, and use SQL-standard naming.  The reason is simple:  How many variants of your database design do you want floating about?  No enterprise geodatabases will allow that naming, so a *drag-n-drop* isn't going to work.  Then the apps need to be rewritten with the new names...  I make sure to avoid reserved words in **any** RDBMS, just to make my geodata implementation-independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @Vince in comments, "table" is a reserved word. After renaming the output table to "tableOutput" the script worked.

```
>>> outTab = r"C:\Users\e1b8\Desktop\E1B8\Snapping\workspace\workspace.gdb\table"
```

changed to:

```
>>> outTab = r"C:\Users\e1b8\Desktop\E1B8\Snapping\workspace\workspace.gdb\tableOutput"
```

Comment: Emil, there are a few more naughty words that should be avoided; have a browse of my answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123736/what-causes-error-000210-cannot-create-output-in-memory-and-from-arcpy/123747#123747 where I wrote some code trying letter combinations and testing failures - it was tedious but interesting.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson the script you've mentioned is good. Using itertools permutations would make it much easier to write and read

Answer (score 0):

what is the purpose of copying new rows? to a make a new table? if you are just trying to make a table with an SQL QRY just use the

```
arcpy.TableSelect_analysis(input, output, sql)
```

Comment: This is just experimentation.