# Create near table to show the distance to every feature chosen in arcgis toolbox

Tags: arcpy, proximity, python-toolbox

I'm scripting a toolbox in which the user chooses a feature containing multiple points to create a distance table from other selected features in the list.

The following script for every loop overwrites the distance. I want every loop output to be written in a new column for every feature.

Any idea?

[image: this is the toolbox inputs and output]

```
import arcpy

Stations = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Dest = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Out = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)



in_features = Stations
near_features = Dest
out_table = Out


for near_features in Dest.split(';'):


out=arcpy.GenerateNearTable_analysis(in_features, near_features, out_table)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see where your problem is, you're trying to append to `Out` but the tool keeps overwriting the output table so you only get the last result.

You would probably want to keep a track of which feature class the particular 'near' relates to, so I suggest trying it this way:

```
import arcpy

Stations = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Dest = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Out = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

in_features = Stations
near_features = Dest
out_table = Out
temp_names = [] # new blank list to keep track of tables generated
for near_features in Dest.split(';'):
    # I'm assuming this is working so far
    # store this near table as an in memory table
    TempTab = 'in_memory\\{}_Table'.format(near_features)
    arcpy.GenerateNearTable_analysis(in_features, near_features, TempTab)
    temp_names.append(TempTab) # add this name to the list of tables to be merged
    arcpy.AddField_management(TempTab,"NearFt","TEXT",field_length=250) # Add a new field to store the feature class name

    # Populate the feature class name for this near 
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(TempTab,"NearFt","\"{}\"".format(near_features),"PYTHON") 

# merge all the temp tables to the output table
arcpy.Merge_management(temp_names,Out)

# clean up resources
for ThisTable in temp_names:
    arcpy.Delete_management(ThisTable)
```

Each individual Near output is stored as a separate table in the [in_memory](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w0000005s000000) workspace, I [add a field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000047000000) to the temporary near table, populating it with the feature class name using [Calculate Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Calculate_Field/00170000004m000000/) then at the end [merge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000055000000) all the temporary tables to the `Out` table, this will give you a single table with *all* the near outputs and provide the feature class name that each particular measurement belongs to.

Comment: Michael, Thank you for your response. I've run this code on IDLE 2.7.12, I've got this error message:   cannot create output in_memory\1_Table

Comment: Michael, I referred to your post here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123736/what-causes-error-000210-cannot-create-output-in-memory-and-from-arcpy                                    I changed {}_Table to R{}_Table to avoid adding a number to the first part of the word. The problem was solved till I got new error which is :                                     line 891, in GenerateNearTable
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (GenerateNearTable).

Comment: After re-running the script the error changes to                                                   ERROR 000725: Output Table: Dataset in_memory\R1_Table already exists.
Failed to execute (GenerateNearTable).

Comment: Ah, that's because arcpy.env.overwriteOutput isn't set to overwrite.. set arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True and that might fix it. It may have fallen over previously and not cleaned up in_memory. Would you by any chance have two feature classes called 'R1'?

Comment: I really appreciate your help. without your help, it was impossible for me to find a solution to this problem.                                                                          If "R1" or any feature like that I had, I would change the "R1" to something els.

Comment: meanwhile, is there any better way to handle this memory issue?

Comment: You could check if the intended output exists with if arcpy.Exists(TempTab): arcpy.Delete_management(TempTab).. If two of your input layers have the same name then, because the name must be unique in the in_memory workspace, the latest would overwrite the previous. You could check all the names first and then raise an error if the layer names aren't unique.. but that is worth a new question. Do your feature classes or layers have numeric names?

Comment: Yes, but I can change them to alphabetic names. In fact, this tool is going to be an input for MATLAB, therefore to avoid creating cell array in MATLAB is changed the names into numeric form.